# REST service returning "useful" information for demos

Tags: web-services, api, rest

I am looking for a REST service that I could use in demo code. I'd like the service:

- To take at least one parameter (as a request parameter, or XML POSTed as the body of the HTTP request).
- To return the result as XML (not JSON).
- To be accessible anonymously (I'll call the service in sample code, so I don't want to put my key in the code, or request users to get a key).

When the Twitter API supported XML (not just JSON), I was typically using their [search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search). But really anything mainstream enough, easy enough to understand will do (information about zip code, weather for a city…).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Yahoo! Weather API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) can be used for this. It takes a location as a request parameter and returns the weather forecast for that location as XML. It also returns weather information as HTML, which you could display as-is to the user. You can see an example of this below. Also make sure that you respect the term of use described at the bottom of the Weather API documentation page.

[image: weather output]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net, why don't you just create a tiny MVC application that has a controller that exposes a method that returns some sort of formatted XML? That way you can run the whole thing locally.

**EDIT:**

You know, I think you can use Google Maps API without a key. I created a test project a couple of days ago. Here is a .Net code snippet (only included so that you can see how I am calling the service):

```
private static string GetString(Uri requestUri)
{
   var output = string.Empty;

   var response = WebRequest.Create(requestUri).GetResponse();
   var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
   if (stream != null)
   {
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
      {
         output = reader.ReadToEnd();
         reader.Close();
      }
   }
   response.Close();
   return output;
}
```

I pass in a uri with a url:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?mode=walking&origin={0},{1}&destination={2},{3}&sensor=false
```

Where `{0},{1}` are the first lat/long, and `{2},{3}` are the second. I am not attaching a key to this and it worked for testing. My method returns a string that later I handle like so:

```
var response = XDocument.Parse(GetString(request));
```

which gives me back xml. Again, I still recommend just creating your own web app and then deploying it somewhere publicly accessible (either in a LAN or on the web), but if you just need a web service to return XML you can use that.

Comment: This would certainly work in certain situations, but not in the one I'm in: I need to be distributing the example as a stand-alone piece of code, and can't afford to ask people to install an additional piece which would implement the service.

Comment: Well, if you hosted your small web app, everyone could just point their sample code at that-- but I can understand if you don't have time for that. Cheers

Comment: @avernet you want to distribute the client or the service?

Comment: @bdares I want to distribute the client. And am looking for a service. Something like the Twitter search API, which now I can't use anymore for that purpose, as it only supports JSON, and doesn't support XML anymore.

Comment: @davecoulter, good find, the Google Maps direction API does not seem to check on the key. For instance: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&sensor=false. But some other Google Maps API do and return a "request denied", for instance: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false. So I am not that I want to rely on this, as it might just work because of an oversight on Google's part.